# What function has replaced bipartite_configuration_model in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have an older piece of code that depends on networkx. I get an error at the last line:

```
    # Generate a random graph with the appropriate degree sequence.
    left_sequence = [left_degree for x in range(L)]
    right_sequence = [right_degree for x in range(R)]
    # Need to use `create_using=Graph()` or else networkx will create a
    # multigraph.
    graph = bipartite_configuration_model(left_sequence, right_sequence,
                                          create_using=Graph(), seed=seed)
```

What function has replaced `bipartite_configuration_model` in newer versions of networkx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`bipartite_configuration_model`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.generators.bipartite.bipartite_configuration_model.html), which I've found in `networkx` 1.9 docs is the same as [`configuration_model`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model), which was moved to the `bipartite` module. As far as I see this was done with the migration to 2.0, but I don't find any explicit mentioning of this.

Comment: you are right. from networkx.algorithms.bipartite import configuration_model solves the problem. Thanks.